# Rich text box doesnt appear in toolbox

Tags: .net, winforms

i select choose item from toolbox then whitch tab select to select rich text box to put in toolbox so i can put it in my form

generaly how can i use rich text box in form

Answer (score 0):

Use the ajax control toolkit's HTML editor control: http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/HTMLEditor/HTMLEditor.aspx